# bulk update postgresql sequences

Tags: database, postgresql, sequence, plpgsql

I have existing data that I want to import in a new system.
I want to set sequences accordingly to the length of existing tables. I try this, but I get `number == 1`.

```
DO
$do$
   DECLARE
   _tbl text;
   number int;
    BEGIN
        FOR _tbl  IN
           SELECT c.relname FROM pg_class c WHERE c.relkind = 'S' and c.relname ilike '%y_id_seq'
        LOOP
        -- EXECUTE
           SELECT count(*) FROM regexp_replace(_tbl, '(\w)y_.*', '\1ies')  INTO number;
           RAISE NOTICE '%', number;
           EXECUTE format('SELECT setval(''"%s"'', ''%s'' )', _tbl, number);
        END LOOP;
    END
$do$;
```

What should I do to get the right count?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`COUNT(*)` is not the best choice for a new sequence value. Just imagine that you have holes in your numbering, for example `1, 2, 15`. `Count` is `3` but next value should be `16` to avoid duplicates in the future.

Assuming you use sequence for `id` column I would suggest:

```
SELECT max(id) FROM _table_name_ INTO number;
```

Or even simpler:

```
SELECT setval(_sequence_name_, max(id)) FROM _table_name_;
```